# How to change tab widget text color using style?

Tags: android, android-layout

My app use ActionBarSherlock.

App theme is Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar (like Holo.Light.DarkActionBar)

And I need 2-depth Tab (1-depth tab is action bar tab), so I make TabHost and TabWidget.

layout.xml

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            **style="@style/TabWidget**
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="TabWidget">
    <item name="android:background">@color/holo_gray_dark</item>
    *==> works fine light(default)->dark*
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/android_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/android_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/android_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/android_white</item>
    *==> these did not work...*
</style>
```

In result, tab widget is dark backgrround and dark text.

How to change tab widget to dark style?